# How do I count two unique values in one column based on another?

Tags: r, variables, unique

If anyone could help with this would be appreciated. I am trying to add two new variables to
my  existing DF (*Grade1Sum and *Grade2Sum) summing each film's grade (ET got graded one three times so the *Grade1Sum total is always equal to 3 for example)

There are only two grades (1 and 2). Hopefully this makes sense, so if anyone can help, would be appreciated (I want to add them to an existing DF, thus currently I only have the first three columns).

I am adding what I want the DF to look like as a pic as it won't format correctly:[image]

**Additional does anyone know how to count the amount of times each grade was received per film?

Comment: Could you please `dput()` your data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Film) %>% 
   mutate(Grade1Sum=sum(Grade[Grade==1]), Grade2Sum=sum(Grade[Grade==2]))
```

Here is a more flexible way to do it

```
df %>%
   group_by(Film, Grade) %>%
   summarise(Sum=sum(Grade)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from=Grade, values_from=Sum,
               names_glue="Grade{Grade}{.value}") %>%
   right_join(., df)
```

Comment: Thank you! That works.

If I used "count" instead of sum in your first solution, would that give the frequency each value occurs?

Comment: No, count is used as a short hand for `summarise(n=n())`. Plus you do not want the count but the sum of the grades, so even if you did use it the result would be incorrect

Comment: Cool thanks, but It later dawned on me that I did want the count so I thought there might be an easy substitution in the code.